# Is it possible to get Code Coverage Analysis on an Interop Assembly?

Tags: interop, com-interop, instrumentation

I've asked this question over on the MSDN forums also and haven't found a resolution:

http://forums.microsoft.com/msdn/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3686852&SiteID=1

The basic problem here as I see it is that an interop assembly doesn't actually contain any IL that can be instrumented (except for maybe a few delegates). So, although I can put together a test project that exercises the interop layer, I can't get a sense for *how many* of those methods and properties I'm actually calling.

Plan B is to go and write a code generator that creates a library of RCWWs (Runtime Callable Wrapper Wrappers), and instrument that for the purposes of code coverage.

Edit: @Franci Penov,

Yes that's exactly what I want to do. The COM components delivered to us constitute a library of some dozen DLLs containing approx. 3000 types. We consume that library in our application and are charged with testing that Interop layer, since the group delivering the libraries to us does minimal testing. Code coverage would allow us to ensure that all interfaces and coclasses are exercised. That's all I'm attempting to do. We have separate test projects that exercise our own managed code.

Yes, ideally the COM server team should be testing and analyzing their own code, but we don't live in an ideal world and I have to deliver a quality product based on their work. If can produce a test report indicating that I've tested 80% of their code interfaces and 50% of those don't work as advertised, I can get fixes done where fixes need to be done, and not workaround problems.

The mock layer you mentioned would be useful, but wouldn't ultimately be achieving the goal of testing the Interop layer itself, and I certainly would not want to be maintaining it by hand -- we are at the mercy of the COM guys in terms of changes to the interfaces.

Like I mentioned above -- the next step is to generate wrappers for the wrappers and instrument those for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question - it's not possible to instrument interop assemblies for code coverage. They contain only metadata, and no executable code as you mention yourself.

Besides, I don't see much point in trying to code coverage the interop assembly. You should be measuring the code coverage of code you write.

From the MDN forums thread you mention, it seems to me you actually want to measure how your code uses the COM component. Unless your code's goal is to enumerate and explicitly call all methods and properties of the COM object, you don't need to measure code coverage. You need unit/scenario testing to ensure that your code is calling the right methods/properties at the right time.

Imho, the right way to do this would be to write a mock layer for the COM object and test that you are calling all the methods/properties as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Plan C:

use something like [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to weave simple execution counters into the interop assembly. For example, check out this one section in the [Faq](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil:FAQ): "I would like to add some tracing functionality to an assembly I can’t debug, is it possible using Cecil?"